# PHP curl working on XAMPP, but not on Server

Tags: php, apache, authentication, curl, server

I transferred my application from my development environment XAMPP to our old Ubuntu Web Server (Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS). On the server, PHP 5.3 is installed.
I enabled curl, which is working.

When I try to run my code, an error occurs "Host not found". I already tried to debug the curl with the help of [this article](https://blog.kettle.io/debugging-curl-requests-in-php/) but I'm not able to figure out what the problem is.

I tried for example the following code:

```
function getTest($parameter, $username, $password){
    $response = file_get_contents_curl('[rest url with parameter]', $username, $password);
    print_r($response);
}

function file_get_contents_curl($url, $username, $password) {
    ob_start();
    $out =fopen('php://output', 'w');
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_STDERR, $out);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)');
    $data = curl_exec($curl);
    fclose($out);
    $debug=ob_get_clean();
    print_r($debug);
    curl_close($curl);
```

The code above contains the debugging code from the article. The following is the output (additionally to the $response output which contains the error "host not found"):

```
GET [rest url] 
HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)
Host: [host]
Accept: */*
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive

< HTTP/1.1 502 Host not found
< Date: Mon, 09 Jan 2017 17:49:42 GMT
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Pragma: no-cache
< Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
< Content-Length: 2556
< Accept-Ranges: none
* HTTP/1.1 proxy connection set close!
< Proxy-Connection: close
< Connection: close
<
* Closing connection #0
```

Does anybody has an idea, what might be the problem in there? Is there a problem with the authentication? The url does not work if I try to access it in the command line either, but the code works in my XAMPP and the url works in the browser.

I really appreciate any help!!!
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is `[rest url]` actually set to a URL?

Comment: yes it is my url (http://.....)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found out, that it works if I use the pure IP instead of the domain name. I'm not familar with network stuff, but it seems that there was a problem with DNS.

But by using the IP in the URL, everything works fine.

Comment: From the question I'm not sure if this is your own domain/IP you're calling. Either way, be aware that the IP might change in the future, if the host moves to a different server, introduces some load balancing mechanism with multiple servers, or that the site might not be available in the server's default directory because of a change in configuration. Figuring out the DNS problem instead of just circumventing it might save you some maintenance headaches in the future.

Comment: Yes, that's true! As I only develop a protoype at the moment, this is enough for me as workaround. But I would be glad if you could explain me, how to figure outh the DNS problem :-)

Comment: That's easier said than done. First of all you'd need to figure out what exactly is going wrong, and where. But I think this goes too far for a comment section, and also I'm not all that much of an expert when it comes to network stuff either. Maybe you'll find help in the [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/)? Also, maybe it wasn't the best move to mark this as the correct answer.